# Scan Debit Card with card.io

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, card.io

I want to scan card in my application for payment.
I am using https://github.com/card-io/card.io-iOS-SDK for scanning cards.
I am able to scan credit  but unable to scan  debit card where the card no. Is that possible to scan debit card with card.io SDK. Is there any possible solutions for that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to card.io issue tracker it appears that the library still does not support cards with printed (not embossed) numbers (e.g. see [this](https://github.com/card-io/card.io-iOS-SDK/issues/166) and [this](https://github.com/card-io/card.io-Android-SDK/issues/155)). I've tried to scan my debit card with an embossed number and it passed well, while cards with printed numbers failed.

[This open source library](https://github.com/CTBConsulting/Card.io-for-Capital-One-vertical-Cards) that integrates with card.io may help you.